# How do I change the voice in Azure text-to-speech?

Tags: reactjs, azure, text-to-speech

I have tried changing my React website to use a UK voice:

```
const voice = "Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-GB, LibbyNeural)"
speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = voice;
speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = "en-GB";
const audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromDefaultMicrophoneInput();

return new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
```

but all I ever hear is a US voice. What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984952/change-speechsynthesis-voice-with-speechrecognition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ryan has pointed out, you'll want to use the SpeechSynthesizer rather than the SpeechRecognizer. Here's a link to the [TTS sample code on github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/quickstart/javascript/node/text-to-speech/index.js).

The sample should clear things up and get you going. Be sure to take note of the audioConfig and speechConfig properties. For example, `speechSynthesisVoiceName` will need a change use the voice name tag as provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#neural-voices). (Further down that page are [standard voices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support#standard-voices)). And `speechRecognitionLanguage` would be replaced with `speechSynthesisLanguage`. Those are just a few examples, but the github samples should clear things up all around.

```
var audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromAudioFileOutput(filename);
var speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(settings.subscriptionKey, settings.serviceRegion);

// setting the synthesis language, voice name, and output audio format.
// see https://aka.ms/speech/tts-languages for available languages and voices
speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = settings.language;
speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-GuyNeural";

// create the speech synthesizer.
var synthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SpeechRecognizer is used to turn speech into text, if you want to turn text into speech you'd need to use the SpeechSynthesizer.